# Is aggregate the right function to use here?

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

consider the following data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(c1=c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6)), 
                c2=c("v1","v1","v2","v3","v3","v1", "v2","v3","v1","v2","v3","v2"), 
                c3=c(1.4,-1.2,1.5,1.6,-1.7,1.2, -1.1,-1.2,1.3,1.5,1.1,-1.9))
```

I want to add a 4th column c4 that counts how many positive and negative numbers are there for "a" and "b" in column c1. However, only those values in c3 should be considered where c2 equals "v1". Furthermore, if there are only positive or negative values an empty string should be printed

So for my example the 4th column should look like:

```
> d
   c1 c2   c3 c4
1   a v1  1.4 2/1
2   a v1 -1.2 2/1
3   a v2  1.5 2/1
4   a v3  1.6 2/1
5   a v3 -1.7 2/1
6   a v1  1.2 2/1
7   b v2 -1.1 " "
8   b v3 -1.2 " "
9   b v1  1.3 " "
10  b v2  1.5 " "
11  b v3  1.1 " "
12  b v2 -1.9 " "
```

for a the value of 2/1 is used as there are two positive numbers and one negative number where c2="v1"

At the moment I came closest using the aggregate function but I still don't really get it right. Not sure if there is a better function to use for that kind of issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anything that uses more than one column (other than the one(s) by which you group), I find `plyr` more convenient:

```
ddply(d, "c1", transform,
               c4 = { pos <- sum(c2 == "v1" & c3 >= 0)
                      neg <- sum(c2 == "v1" & c3 < 0)
                      ifelse(pos * neg == 0, ' ', paste(pos, neg, sep = '/')) })

#    c1 c2   c3  c4
# 1   a v1  1.4 2/1
# 2   a v1 -1.2 2/1
# 3   a v2  1.5 2/1
# 4   a v3  1.6 2/1
# 5   a v3 -1.7 2/1
# 6   a v1  1.2 2/1
# 7   b v2 -1.1    
# 8   b v3 -1.2    
# 9   b v1  1.3    
# 10  b v2  1.5    
# 11  b v3  1.1    
# 12  b v2 -1.9
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you guys so late. had some other stuff to do in between. I really appreciate your work you have done here! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use plain R-base `aggregate` should be your friend:

```
ag <- aggregate.data.frame(
  d$c3,
  by = list(d$c1, d$c2),
  FUN = function(x){ paste(sum(x < 0), sum(x>0), sep="/") }
)
> ag
  Group.1 Group.2   x
1       a      v1 1/2
2       b      v1 0/1
3       a      v2 0/1
4       b      v2 2/1
5       a      v3 1/1
6       b      v3 1/1
```

Then you can just `merge` the aggregated data into your original data.frame:

```
d <- merge( d, ag, by.x = c( "c1", "c2" ), by.y = c( "Group.1", "Group.2" ), all.x = TRUE )
```

However, I'd recommend using `ddply` from `plyr` package due to its simplicity:

```
library("plyr")
d <- ddply( d, c("c1","c2"), function(x) {
  x$c4 <- paste(sum( x$c3 < 0), sum(x$c3 > 0), sep="/")
  return(x)
})
```

**EDIT:**

After having reread the question, this should be the right solution using `aggregate`:

```
d.sub <- d[ d$c2 == "v1", , drop=FALSE ]
ag <- aggregate(
  d.sub$c3,
  by = list(d.sub$c1),
  FUN = function(x){ # taken from @flodel
    pos <- sum(x < 0);
    neg <- sum( x > 0 );
    ifelse( pos * neg == 0, "", paste( pos, neg, sep="/") )
  }
)
d <- merge( d, ag, by.x = "c1", by.y = "Group.1", all.x = TRUE  )
```

Concerning the `ddply` @flodel's solution is how I'd do it either.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem, `c1` should be the only grouping variable. Then, inside each group, the results are only based on a data subset where `c2 == "v1"`. It's pretty clear from the OP's description and expected output.

Comment: I feel you've proven that `aggregate` might not be the best tool for this particular task, as the `merge` step would be pretty costly. If I were to use a `base` approach here, then maybe a `split/lapply/rbind` would be better. Which is what `ddply` does for you.

Comment: @flodel thats why wrote "I'd recommend using ddply". But it was not me who asked for `aggregate` and sometimes you have to see the ugly solution to appreciate the simple one.

Comment: I also want to thank you for your efforts in showing us that ddply should be used over the aggregate function for this particular task. Great thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution with `ddply` using a slightly different approach:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d, .(c1), transform, c4 = {
                        tab <- table(factor(sign(c3[c2 == "v1"]), c(1, -1))); 
                        ifelse(any(tab == 0), " ", paste(tab, collapse = "/")) })



#    c1 c2   c3  c4
# 1   a v1  1.4 2/1
# 2   a v1 -1.2 2/1
# 3   a v2  1.5 2/1
# 4   a v3  1.6 2/1
# 5   a v3 -1.7 2/1
# 6   a v1  1.2 2/1
# 7   b v2 -1.1    
# 8   b v3 -1.2    
# 9   b v1  1.3    
# 10  b v2  1.5    
# 11  b v3  1.1    
# 12  b v2 -1.9
```

Comment: IMHO, harder to decipher. Also not very flexible around zeroes.

Comment: @flodel Why do you think it's not very flexible around zeroes?

Comment: Because `sign(0)` equals `0`, no? So they are removed by your current code. If the user wanted instead to count zeroes towards one or the other (positives or negatives), that wouldn't be super easy.

Comment: @flodel Agreed, but if the user wanted to count zeroes as a separate category (e.g., `2/0/1`), the modifications were: (1) Add `, 0` to the factor levels and (2) replace `any(tab == 0)` by `sum(tab == 0) > 1`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution too. I ticked the first answer as I thought it is slightly more readable even though I am sure it works great :-) thanks!